# When are package objects initialized?

Tags: scala, package

If I define a package object

```
package com.something.else

package object more {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis
    // ... other stuff ...
}
```

which is then imported somewhere in the source code.

```
import com.something.else.more
```

When is this object (and its members) initialized/constructed?

In other words, what determines the value of `more.time`?
Is it evaluated when the program first starts? Or the first time it is accessed? Or the first time `more` is accessed?

Comment: My guess would be when the class loader first loads more, but I can't check that right now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy to check:

```
package something

package object more {
  val time = System.currentTimeMillis
}

// in separate file:
package something.more

object Test extends App {
  val now = System.currentTimeMillis

  Thread.sleep(1000)

  println(now)
  println(time)
}
```

gives:

```
1339394348495
1339394349496
```

The second time is ~1000 ms later, so it's when the package object is first accessed, as it would be with any other object.