# Scala package object constructor

Tags: scala

When and how is the Scala Package object constructor called?

I have two classes:

Package.scala

```
package my;
package object entities {
   //Some initialization code in constructor
}
```

Classy.scala

```
package my.entities;
case class Classy {
}
```

I am trying to have the entities constructor to have already been executed by the time an object of Classy is created.

Comment: you could try to put two println in the initialization of the package object and case class and see in what order they get printed to screen.

Comment: Actually the "entities" constructor doesn't get called at all. I want to know, how to call it. I would assume it should be called automatically whenever a package class is created or imported...?

Comment: it's created (and initialized) when it's first used. Try doing val c = Classy . See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973692/when-are-package-objects-initialized

Comment: I created an object of Classy but it doesn't get called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package object is translated into a normal java class file called *package.class* IIRC. From then on I assume it behaves like any normal Java class, thus it is loaded and instantiated when it is first referenced. In Scala, that means you need to define some method or `val` in the package object, then access it from outside. In your case, you may try calling it from the constructor of `Classy`, or from the code which instantiates `Classy`.

#### Update

OK, here is some code I ran to test what I described above:

```
// package.scala
package some

package object pkg {
  println("package created!")

  def func() { println("func called") }
}

// C.scala
package some.pkg

class C {
  println("created C")
}

// G.scala
package some.pkg

object G {
  println("creating G")
  func()
  println("created G")
}

// PackageTester.scala
package some.pkg

object PackageTester extends App {
  val c = new C
  val g = G
}
```

And the output is:

```
created C
creating G
package created!
func called
created G
```

Which proves that Scala package objects are created lazily, only when they are actually referenced. And in fact the same is true for "normal" Scala objects, as demonstrated by `G` above.

Comment: As it is an object and not a class, shouldn't the constructor be called automatically?

Comment: Objects are *lazy*. They're not instantiated until they are used. I would assume the same applies for package objects. Try *using* the (package) object, and the constructor should be called.

Comment: Your program seems side-effect heavy. What exactly are you trying to do? This sounds "dangerous" :P

Comment: Doesn't creating an object of a class within a package mean using package object?

Comment: @0n4li, definitely not. Terminology wise, they sound as if they were related, but package objects are more like a convenience to "emulate" free (global) functions in Scala. And if you take into account the Java implementation of these, it is clear that there is no implicit dependency between a class/object residing in a package, and the corresponding package object.

Comment: @0n4li, now I got to fix my IDE and run some tests; please see my update.

Comment: Well it doesn't work I thought it would and I understand why. Anyways, I used your solution. Thanks.